# How to display a property in JSP based on another property

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a jsp in which I am showing a table like

```
<tr class="even">                
<td><bean:write name="itemDetails" property="recived"/></td>                                         
<td><bean:write name="itemDetails" property="actioned"/></td>
<td> <bean:write name="itemDetails" property="internalUser"/></td> 
<td> <bean:write name="itemDetails" property="action"/>   </td>
 </tr>  </logic:iterate>
```

here property actioned is Date in format `08/05/2014 14:34`.

Now I want to show property internalUser for row if actioned property is not more than 6 months old else hide it, Can anyone help how to proceed?

Comment: Well there is no class named itemDetails, I am iterating a list here                         

<logic:iterate id="itemDetails" indexId="index" name="bookingHistorySearchForm" property="results.currentPage" >
  <tr class="even">
                                       
 <td><bean:write name="itemDetails" property="recived"/></td>                                         
 <td><bean:write name="itemDetails" property="actioned"/></td>
  <td> <bean:write name="itemDetails" property="internalUser"/></td> 
   <td>  <bean:write name="itemDetails" property="action"/>  </td>
    </tr>
 </logic:iterate>

Answer (score 1):

Create another property in the `itemDetails`, for example

```
private boolean showInternalUser;

public boolean getShowInternalUser() {
   // compare difference between `actioned time` and `new Date()` here (6 months)
   // and return true if you need to display the property `internalUser`
}

public void setShowInternalUser(boolean showInternalUser) {
   this.showInternalUser = showInternalUser;
}
```

Then in `jsp` change:

```
<td> <bean:write name="itemDetails" property="internalUser"/></td>
```

to

```
<td>
   <c:if test="${itemDetails.showInternalUser}">
      <c:out value="${itemDetails.internalUser}"/>
   </c:if>
</td>
```

Comment: Well there is no class named itemDetails, I am iterating a list here

Comment: Well there is no class named itemDetails, I am iterating a list here                         

<logic:iterate id="itemDetails" indexId="index" name="bookingHistorySearchForm" property="results.currentPage" >
  <tr class="even">
                                       
 <td><bean:write name="itemDetails" property="recived"/></td>                                         
 <td><bean:write name="itemDetails" property="actioned"/></td>
  <td> <bean:write name="itemDetails" property="internalUser"/></td> 
   <td>  <bean:write name="itemDetails" property="action"/>  </td>
    </tr>
 </logic:iterate>

Comment: So you can modify the property `currentPage` the same way.